# Possible to prevent iPhone from automatically joining known networks?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

The Wi-Fi settings description of "Ask to Join Networks" says "Known networks will be joined automatically...". That "feature" is causing me problems.

I have a local wi-fi router in my home office which is above the garage and far from the family room at the other end of the house, where there's another wi-fi network with a different name. If I ever leave my office and walk towards the family room, my iPhone jumps to the family-room network but it doesn't jump back on to my office wifi network when I return to my computer. When I'm in my office, the reception for the FamilyRoomNetwork is very weak and it is very slow.

Can this be fixed, either by causing an automatic rejoin of my office wifi network when I return to my desk or by forcing the phone to ask my permission to switch to another known network?

P.S. I do want to join the FamilyRoomNetwork at the end of the day, so I don't want to remove it.

Comment: Can you see in the wifi network info   a choice « auto connect ». You can configure auto connection network by network.

Comment: Ah, that was on a page that opens up when the `(i)` info icon is tapped. Thank you.  I am like a dog who has been trained to look for the `gear` icon for settings :-)

Comment: @PtitXav that is the answer. I'd give you the kudos if you wrote it as an answer and not a comment :)

Comment: If they are sourced from the same broadband provider, the ideal approach here is to configure the wifi networks so they are one contiguous network.  There are ways to do that.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica : In this case they're different broadband providers. We had no internet for nearly a month a few years ago; it took them weeks to actually come out and look at their wire on the pole where the problem was eventually discovered. Ever since then I've had two.

Comment: @Tim oh yeah, I did that myself for awhile (albeit in an 800sf cottage so you could always reach both services).  I would still take the time to either wired or wirelessly link the networks so they are 1 network taking from 1 provider.  And so you can easily source it from either provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to   the wifi network  info , there is a a choice « auto connect ». You can configure auto connection network by network